# Writing to MySQL database with pandas using SQLAlchemy, to_sql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, mysql-connector

trying to write pandas dataframe to MySQL table using `to_sql`.  Previously been using `flavor='mysql'`, however it will be depreciated in the future and wanted to start the transition to using SQLAlchemy engine.

sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', echo=False)
cnx = engine.raw_connection()
data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM sample_table', cnx)
data.to_sql(name='sample_table2', con=cnx, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

The read works fine but the `to_sql` has an error:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
>   WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Wrong number of arguments during
>   string formatting

Why does it look like it is trying to use sqlite? What is the correct use of a sqlalchemy connection with mysql and specifically mysql.connector?

I also tried passing the engine in as the connection as well, and that gave me an error referencing no cursor object.

```
data.to_sql(name='sample_table2', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
>>AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Comment: You have to pass the Engine itself, not a raw connection (in the future an sqlalchemy Connection will also be possible, but not a raw connection). Can you see if that solves the problem?

Comment: Ah, I see that you already tried that :-) Can you show the error you get in that case?

Comment: when using engine: AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Comment: Can you show the output of `pd.__versions__`? You're sure not picking up an old pandas version?

Comment: pd.__version__ is 0.16.1, assuming you meant `__version__` not `__versions__`

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? (when using IPython eg?) to see from which lines this error comes. We don't use cursors anymore in the new implementation, so this error is a bit strange

Comment: Yes, this error was really strange.  I restarted my environment and went through the process again this morning.  I used a sqlalchemy engine and it worked.  I am perplexed at what was different.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Using the engine in place of the `raw_connection()` worked:

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', echo=False)
data.to_sql(name='sample_table2', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

Not clear on why when I tried this yesterday it gave me the earlier error.

Comment: Glad it works now! In any case, this is the way to go

Comment: BTW, you may accept your own answer to indicated this is fixed!

Comment: In case you run into problems installing `mysql.connector` or don't know how to install it, see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32754461/how-to-install-mysql-connector-via-pip
They recommend `pip install mysql-connector==2.1.4`. It also solved this problem for me.

Comment: Consistently getting error Python installation has no SSL support. Running with python 3.7 with fresh Anaconda install.

Comment: I have @ in password filed and it's creating an issue. How can we fix this.

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://dbuser:DBuser@12345@xyz/table")

Here DBuser@12345 is password. but somehow script not able to interpret it correct.
It user 12345@xyz as hostname instead of xyz

Comment: [Suggestion for a faster way] With `SQLAlchemy>=1.3`, while creating `engine` object, set `fast_executemany=True`. [Reference](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#fast-executemany-mode)

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, use `pymysql` package...

```
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
cnx = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', echo=False)

data = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM sample_table', cnx)
data.to_sql(name='sample_table2', con=cnx, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

Comment: openwonk - can you elaborate on the `[port]/[schema]` portion of this code?  Not exactly sure what to put there.  Thank you!

Comment: Gonna answer my own question here, schema = data base.

Comment: Glad to help, @pshep123

Comment: Although I'm still having a hell of a time here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44933704/pandas-0-20-2-to-sql-using-mysql. Not sure if you have any insight, thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any other specifics about why connection refused? Could be entirely unrelated to Python, Pandas, and SQLAlchemy.

Comment: This is the only solution I found that is working with Python 3

Comment: I spent forever trying to find an answer like this that worked!

Answer (score 8):

Using pymysql and sqlalchemy,  this works for Pandas v0.22:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

user = 'yourUserName'
passw = 'password'
host =  'hostName'  # either localhost or ip e.g. '172.17.0.2' or hostname address 
port = 3306 
database = 'dataBaseName'

mydb = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://' + user + ':' + passw + '@' + host + ':' + str(port) + '/' + database , echo=False)

directory = r'directoryLocation'  # path of csv file
csvFileName = 'something.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory, csvFileName ))

df.to_sql(name=csvFileName[:-4], con=mydb, if_exists = 'replace', index=False)

"""
if_exists: {'fail', 'replace', 'append'}, default 'fail'
     fail: If table exists, do nothing.
     replace: If table exists, drop it, recreate it, and insert data.
     append: If table exists, insert data. Create if does not exist.
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I know in the title of the question is included the word SQLAlchemy, however I see in the questions and answers the need to import pymysql or mysql.connector, and also is possible to do the job with pymysql, withouth calling SQLAlchemy.

```
import pymysql
user = 'root'
passw = 'my-secret-pw-for-mysql-12ud' # In previous posts variable "pass"
host =  '172.17.0.2'
port = 3306

database = 'sample_table' # In previous posts similar to "schema"

conn = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                       port=port,
                       user=user, 
                       passwd=passw,  
                       db=database)

data.to_sql(name=database, con=conn, if_exists = 'append', index=False, flavor = 'mysql')
```

I think this solution could be good althought it is not using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: The flavor keyword arg no longer is allowed.

Comment: Please rename "database" to "table". That way it is very misleading and wrong.

Comment: was looking all over for an answer like this