# How to install mysql-connector via pip

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-connector

I use sqlalchemy to access MySQL in my Python project. sqlalchemy's conf is like this:

```
dialect=mysql
driver=mysqlconnector
```

So I need to install the Python module mysql connector via pip. Any help?

Comment: The official package name now is **`mysql-connector-python`**, so use `pip install mysql-connector-python`

Answer (score 56):

If loading via `pip install mysql-connector` and leads an error `Unable to find Protobuf include directory` then this would be useful `pip install mysql-connector==2.1.4`

`mysql-connector` is obsolete, so use `pip install mysql-connector-python`. [Same here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215390/unable-to-find-protobuf-include-directory-when-i-use-pip-install-mysql-connec)

Comment: Requirements

mysql-connector (version >= 2.2.3) requires Protobuf C++ (version >= 2.6.0)

see https://github.com/sanpingz/mysql-connector

Comment: I have edited and added to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215390/unable-to-find-protobuf-include-directory-when-i-use-pip-install-mysql-connec

Comment: Oracle has finally decided to upload their package (including wheels) to PyPI. So it's now "mysql-connector-python" instead of the deprecated unofficial repackage of "mysql-connector". https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/

Answer (score 29):

To install the **official** MySQL Connector for Python, please use the name **`mysql-connector-python`**:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

---

Some further discussion, when we `pip search` for `mysql-connector` at this time (Nov, 2018), the most related results shown as follow:

```
$ pip search mysql-connector | grep ^mysql-connector
mysql-connector (2.1.6)                  - MySQL driver written in Python
mysql-connector-python (8.0.13)          - MySQL driver written in Python
mysql-connector-repackaged (0.3.1)       - MySQL driver written in Python
mysql-connector-async-dd (2.0.2)         - mysql async connection
mysql-connector-python-rf (2.2.2)        - MySQL driver written in Python
mysql-connector-python-dd (2.0.2)        - MySQL driver written in Python
```

- `mysql-connector (2.1.6)` is provided on PyPI when MySQL didn't provide their official `pip install` on PyPI at beginning (which was inconvenient). But it **is a fork, and is stopped updating,** so

  ```
  pip install mysql-connector
  ```

  will install this obsolete version.
- And now `mysql-connector-python (8.0.13)` on PyPI is the official package maintained by MySQL, so this is the one we should install.

Answer (score 26):

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

Last but not least,You can also install mysql-connector via source code

Download source code from:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Comment: related pages:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector
https://github.com/sanpingz/mysql-connector

Answer (score 7):

execute following command from your terminal

```
sudo pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I have no idea why "allow external" would be important.

Comment: This worked for me too. However, you probably shouldn't use `sudo` for this.

Comment: Worked for me :D (Without sudo) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows

pip install mysql-connector

For Ubuntu /Linux

sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql

Answer (score 0):

First install setuptools

```
sudo pip install setuptools
```

Then install mysql-connector

```
sudo pip install mysql-connector
```

If using Python3, then replace pip by pip3