# "Unable to find Protobuf include directory" when I use "pip install mysql-connector"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, protocol-buffers

I get this error when I try to load using pip install mysql-connector. I tried pip install Protobuf too but no solution.

`# Python architecture: 64-bit
 # Python ARCH_64BIT: True
 Unable to find Protobuf include directory.`

Answer (score 3):

I found this useful:

pip install mysql-connector==2.1.4 is obsolete. `pip install mysql-connector-python` is suggested.

Comment: could you solve the issue with the most recent version?

Answer (score 1):

The **official** package name of MySQL Connector for Python is **`mysql-connector-python`**:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

And `mysql-connector` is a fork package, and is stopped updating, so

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

will install this obsolete version.