# Unable to locate package mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm trying to install mysql.connecter by using "sudo apt install mysql.connecter". But i am getting bug as"Unable to locate package mysql.connector" can anyone help me please to solve this bug.

Comment: Use `pip install mysql-connector-python`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install mysql-connector via pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32754461/how-to-install-mysql-connector-via-pip)

Comment: command 'pip' is not found by terminal in ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Run `pip3 -V`, if available use `pip3 install mysql-connector-python`. Otherwise, you need to save [this](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) as `get-pip.py` and run `python get-pip.py` to install pip. After that you can try `pip install mysql-connector-python`