# Writing a Pandas Dataframe to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe

I'm trying to write a Python Pandas Dataframe to a MySQL database. I realize that it's possible to use sqlalchemy [for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627520/insert-pandas-dataframe-to-mysql-using-sqlalchemy), but I'm wondering if there is another way that may be easier, preferably already built into Pandas. I've spent quite some time trying to do it with a For loop, but it's not realiable.

If anyone knows of a better way, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: to_sql method http://stackoverflow.com/a/16477603/2027457 or http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: The to_sql method works for me.

However, keep in mind that the it looks like it's going to be deprecated in favor of SQLAlchemy:

    FutureWarning: The 'mysql' flavor with DBAPI connection is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. MySQL will be further supported with SQLAlchemy connectables. chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)

Comment: so far still is active so till will be deprecated than will take some time and if you are not upgrading pandas than should be working. posting the answer than.

Comment: Why is sqlalchemy being avoided? All you need is to initialize the engine instead of raw connection, replacing flavor with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other option to **sqlalchemy** can be used **to_sql** but in future released will be deprecated but now in version **pandas 0.18.1 documentation** is still active.

According to pandas documentation [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) you can use following syntax:

```
DataFrame.to_sql(name, con, flavor='sqlite', schema=None, if_exists='fail', index=True, index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None)
```

you specify the con **type/mode** and flavor **‘mysql’**, here is some description:

> con : SQLAlchemy engine or DBAPI2 connection (legacy mode)
>   Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that library. If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported.
>
> flavor : {‘sqlite’, ‘mysql’}, default ‘sqlite’ The flavor of SQL to
>    use. Ignored when using SQLAlchemy engine. ‘mysql’ is deprecated and
>    will be removed in future versions, but it will be further supported
>    through SQLAlchemy engines.

Answer (score 4):

You can  do it by using pymysql:

For example, let's suppose you have a MySQL database with the next user, password, host and port and you want to write in the database 'data_2'.

```
import pymysql
user = 'root'
passw = 'my-secret-pw-for-mysql-12ud'
host =  '172.17.0.2'
port = 3306
database = 'data_2'
```

**If you already have the database created**:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                       port=port,
                       user=user, 
                       passwd=passw,  
                       db=database,
                       charset='utf8')

data.to_sql(name=database, con=conn, if_exists = 'replace', index=False, flavor = 'mysql')
```

**If you do NOT have the database created**, also valid when the database is already there:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, port=port, user=user, passwd=passw)

conn.cursor().execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {0} ".format(database))
conn = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                       port=port,
                       user=user, 
                       passwd=passw,  
                       db=database,
                       charset='utf8')

data.to_sql(name=database, con=conn, if_exists = 'replace', index=False, flavor = 'mysql')
```

Similar threads:

1. [Writing to MySQL database with pandas using SQLAlchemy, to_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631325/writing-to-mysql-database-with-pandas-using-sqlalchemy-to-sql/48116232#48116232)
2. [How to insert pandas dataframe via mysqldb into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476413/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-via-mysqldb-into-database/16477603#16477603)

Comment: It appears this doesn't work in 0.25. The to_sql call no longer supports flavor= and assumes it's a sqlite connection if it's not a sqlalchemy connectable.