# Pandas only support SQL Alchemy connectable

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

So, when trying to read data from a stored procedure using pandas (into a data frame no less) I get the following error.

> Pandas only support SQL Alchemy connectable

It is occurring on this line

```
 data = pd.read_sql_query(storedProc2, engine)
```

This seems to be a pretty common issue for people as I have found out, and after following the advice from multiples posts here, setting the connection string as suggested (see below for the code where I am setting it) but can't seem to figure out why it doesn't like what I am doing.

```
    import pyodbc
    import sys
    import os
    from mymodules import ODBC, SendEmail, MyLogging
    import pandas as pd
    import gc
    import sqlalchemy as sqlEngine
    import urllib

    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver="{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}",server="server",database="db",uid="uid",pwd="pwd")
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    storedProc = "exec GetMaxValuesForETL"
    ODBC.RunSQL("CanvasReporting", "exec [dbo].[TruncateStageTablesETL]")
    for irow in cursor.execute(storedProc):
        strObj = " "+str(irow[0])
        strTbl = str(irow[2])
        cnxn2 = "driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server; server=server; database=db; uid=uid; pwd=pwd"
        params = urllib.parse.quote_plus (cnxn2)
        conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)            
        engine = sqlEngine.create_engine(conn_str)
        storedProc2 = "exec "+strObj+" '"+str(irow[1])+"' "
        data = pd.read_sql_query(storedProc2, engine)
        data.to_sql(name=strTbl, schema='stage', con=cnxn, if_exists='append', index=False)
        del data
        qc.colect()
```

This is what I get from the command line as I am running the code.

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:761: UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy
> warnings.warn(
>
> 2022-07-25 15:37:09,831: CanvasReportingETL.py: INFO: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Connection is busy with results for another command (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: You know for as common as the error message seems to be I thought it was obvious but I guess not lol

Comment: Firstly, make the question self contained i.e. repeat the title. Second always actually ask a question, we are real people here, while we don't want fluffy stuff, we want more than an error dump+code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete stack trace.

Comment: @gordThompson how do i get that for you?

Comment: Error messages are usually written to the stderr device, or in the case of web applications they would be written to a log file. How do you run your code?

Comment: @GordThompson I run it from the commandline. I included the error output it gave me. I also log the same information in a log file.

Comment: The error is caused by `.to_sql(…, con=cnxn, …)`, same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69253030/2144390).

Comment: Oh shit i see it now, I need to do the sql alchemy style connection for both pd.read_sql_query and data.to_sql. OK that was painfully obvious and im dumb, thank you.