# Insert dataframe into pl/sql table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I'm struggling trying to insert a dataframe into a pl/sql table. I can query tables from my own schema w/out issues so the connection is fine. The dataframe shows up fine, but the last line throws me:

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

```
     import os 
     import datetime as dt
     import cx_Oracle
     import sqlalchemy
 
     username = '****'
     password = '****'

     dsn = '(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=15)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=3)\
       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=***)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)\
       (SERVICE_NAME=***)))'
     enc = 'utf-8'

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password=password, dsn=dsn, encoding=enc)
cursor = connection.cursor()

sessions = glob.glob('path to daily file/*file with timestamp @ end of name*.csv')
latest_sessions = max(sessions, key=os.path.getctime, default = 0)

dfSessions = pd.read_csv(latest_sessions, sep=',', index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
dfSessions.drop([drop several columns], axis=1, inplace=True)

dfSessions.head(5)

dfSessions.to_sql('ARRAY_SESSIONS_NEW', connection,schema='BXP6281', if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["SELECT name FROM sqlite\_master" error while uploading DataFrame using .to\_sql()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253030/select-name-from-sqlite-master-error-while-uploading-dataframe-using-to-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use bind variables in a places where they are not allowed. Hence the error.

reference: [oracle - ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number when running query through C# - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375288/ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number-when-running-query-through-c-sharp)