# Pandas to_sql to sqlite returns 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a working_df in pandas I'd like to output to sqlite database.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

sql_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=False)
working_df.to_sql('data', sql_engine,index=False, if_exists='append')
```

returns: `AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'`

Any thoughts?

Pandas version `'0.18.1'`

Edit: Added full trace

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-4f64fc939721> in <module>()
----> 1 working_df.to_sql('data', engine, index=False, if_exists='append')

/Users/tom/anaconda/envs/data_science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
   1163         sql.to_sql(self, name, con, flavor=flavor, schema=schema,
   1164                    if_exists=if_exists, index=index, index_label=index_label,
-> 1165                    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
   1166 
   1167     def to_pickle(self, path):

/Users/tom/anaconda/envs/data_science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    569     pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
    570                       index_label=index_label, schema=schema,
--> 571                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
    572 
    573 

/Users/tom/anaconda/envs/data_science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype)
   1659                             if_exists=if_exists, index_label=index_label,
   1660                             dtype=dtype)
-> 1661         table.create()
   1662         table.insert(chunksize)
   1663 

/Users/tom/anaconda/envs/data_science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in create(self)
    688 
    689     def create(self):
--> 690         if self.exists():
    691             if self.if_exists == 'fail':
    692                 raise ValueError("Table '%s' already exists." % self.name)

/Users/tom/anaconda/envs/data_science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in exists(self)
    676 
    677     def exists(self):
--> 678         return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
    679 
    680     def sql_schema(self):

/Users/tom/anaconda/envs/data_science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in has_table(self, name, schema)
   1674         query = flavor_map.get(self.flavor)
   1675 
-> 1676         return len(self.execute(query, [name, ]).fetchall()) > 0
   1677 
   1678     def get_table(self, table_name, schema=None):

/Users/tom/anaconda/envs/data_science/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1557             cur = self.con
   1558         else:
-> 1559             cur = self.con.cursor()
   1560         try:
   1561             if kwargs:

AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Comment: Are you sure that is is picking up the correct pandas version? Can you show the output of `pd.__version__` in the same session as where you get that error? As you get typically this error if you have an older pandas version (< 0.14)

Comment: `pd.__version__` returns `'0.18.1'`, I had seen it was an older pandas issue which is why it was strange

Comment: going on the older issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631325/writing-to-mysql-database-with-pandas-using-sqlalchemy-to-sql, I did a `engine.raw_connection()` which when applied to the `to_sql`, it seemed to work

Comment: Hmm, strange. Can you show the full error message?

Comment: added, I wonder if its something with the conda environment

Comment: For some reason, it thinks that it is not a sqlalchemy engine (so falls back to sqlite connection). Can you show the output of `pd.io.sql._is_sqlalchemy_connectable(sql_engine)`?

Comment: that returns `False`

Comment: And `isinstance(sql_engine, sqlalchemy.engine.Connectable)`?

Comment: so I think you pointed me in the right direction, I had started up a jupyter notebook and only conda installed sqlalchemy in a second instance of the same env after it mentioned it wasn't installed in this env, so it was never initialized. I restarted the whole session and redid it, and it works w/o the raw_connection. Thanks @joris

Comment: Ah, glad it is solved! maybe update your answer for if people run into the same situation

Answer (score 50, accepted):

adding in a raw_connection() worked for me

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

sql_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=False)
connection = sql_engine.raw_connection()
working_df.to_sql('data', connection, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

I had `conda install sqlalchemy` during my notebook session, so while it was accessible, since I already initiated pandas, it appeared as if there was no sqlalchemy. Restarting the session allowed me to remove the raw_connection().

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

sql_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=False)
connection = sql_engine
working_df.to_sql('data', connection, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: I was using Jupyter. After `pip install sqlalchemy`, I just needed to restart the Jupyter kernel for pandas to be able to use sqlalchemy.

Comment: I was in a REPL and installed SQLAlchemy in another terminal tab without restarting the REPL. The overall takeaway seems to be that SQLAlchemy needs to be available when Pandas is loaded for this to work.

Comment: Exactly true, @jjmontes. Resart before trying anything.

Comment: For me, no restart issue, this change from `connect()` to `raw_connection()` made it. On top of that, `with` statement on the connection was also not possible, I have to manually `conn.close()` it in the end, see [Python Error: AttributeError: __enter__ [without the markup: \_\_enter\_\_])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427729/python-error-attributeerror-enter). I thought sqlalchemy was a standard?

Comment: Please check **Solution for 2024** for pandas >2.2.0 (and help voting up)

Answer (score 31):

## Solution for 2024

*I know this question is old, but a recent change to Pandas warrants a new solution*

Pandas 2.2.0 *appears* to have modified how a SQLAlchemy `Engine` object operates when passed to the `con` argument for `pd.read_sql`, `pd.to_sql`, etc. Unsure if this is intentional.

My project worked perfectly fine with Pandas 2.1.4.
When updated to 2.2.0, I receive the AttributeError due to the `cursor` not being present.

- **Solution: Use the `connection` attribute of a SQLAlchemy `Connection` object instead of the `Engine` object directly.**

Peep this example:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd


# Engine for MS SQL Server using pymssql
conn_url = f"mssql+pymssql://{username}:{password}@{host}/{database}"
engine = create_engine(conn_url)

# Example query
query = 'select id from users'

# Works with pandas<2.2.0
df = pd.read_sql(
    sql=query,
    con=engine,
)

# Works with pandas==2.2.0
with engine.connect() as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql(
        sql=query,
        con=conn.connection
    )
```

Comment: You, sir, are a hero! Thank you so much! I run into this error after updating pandas today..

Comment: Just spent three hours trying to debug this, this is what finally fixed it! Thanks for the heads up

Comment: This should be the first answer now

Comment: Cheers mate! Exactly the answer I was looking for. Pandas is still throwing warnings each time I call `read_sql` but at least it's working.

Comment: I suspect this is [this pandas issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/57049),  relating to Pandas 2.2.0 setting the [minimum supported version of SQLAlchemy to 2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.2.0.html#increased-minimum-versions-for-dependencies).

Comment: Ah that explains it - as snowflake-sqlalchemy doesn't support 2.0 yet (there is a PR), as of 2024-02-26.

Answer (score 7):

The following code was giving me the same error while I was working to push data to MS Sql Server:

```
engine_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://'+username_dsdb+':'+password_dsdb+'@'+server_dsdb+':1433/'+database_dsdb+'?driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_string,deprecate_large_types=True)

conn_dsdb = engine.connect()

df_year_week_contract_wise.to_sql("KPIEngine_FACT_Historical", conn_dsdb, index=False, if_exists='append')

conn_dsdb.close()
```

But, then I restarted the session and it worked fine.

Comment: For me similarly i needed to restart session (for jupyter restart kernel) . I think main problem is on the same python session  previously there was a connection (likely with pyodbc) but it hanged and was not closed properly (happens not using with context).

Answer (score 4):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
sql_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=False)
working_df.to_sql('data', sql_engine,index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Instead of above code, can you try to use connect method of the engine object instead of engine object itself as below.,

```
sql_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=False)
conn = sql_engine.connect()
working_df.to_sql('data', conn,index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Try above steps and let me know if you still facing the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue of this post. I tried your suggestion but the error now is `AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'`.

Comment: @LucasAimaretto Neither connection nor engine do not have cursor method. I assume the cursor purpose for you is to fetch the results stored. You can use execute method of connection for this purpose. You can refer [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I had the same error this week and it turned out that there was a problem with MySQLdb on my Mac.  As a test I tried to ‘import MySQLdb as mysql’ and discovered an ImportError: “Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib”

The solution in my case was to add a symbolic link to the missing library as suggested in [Python mysqldb: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `raw_connection`, using the `connection` attribute on a connection seems to work with pandas>2, sqlalchemy<2.

```py
with sql_engine.connect() as connection:
    working_df.to_sql("data", connection.connection, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

In this way you can still use the context manager and have the connection closed.

Answer (score 1):

Austin is a lifesaver.

To make this work until pandas is updated and works nicely with sqlalchemy, make sure you pandas version is <2.2 and sqlalchemy<2.0

My setting to get this to stop erroring:
pandas==2.1.*
sqlalchemy==1.4.*

To supress sqlalchemy warning, add this:
from sqlalchemy.util import deprecations
deprecations.SILENCE_UBER_WARNING = True

Comment: I'm honestly puzzled by this: SQLA 2.0.27 and Pandas 2.2.0 execute `df.to_sql` without any issues for me.

Comment: Ah, never mind, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332787/pandas-to-sql-to-sqlite-returns-engine-object-has-no-attribute-cursor#comment137549678_77949093)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it's because just pip install the sqlalchemy and didn't restart the jupyter.

So what just need to do is restart the kernel...