# Python Error: AttributeError: __enter__

Tags: python, python-3.x, crazyflie

I receive the attribute error when I try to run the code.

```
    with ParamExample(URI) as pe:
    with MotionCommander(pe, default_height=0.3)as mc:
```

This is where the error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test44.py", line 156, in <module>
with ParamExample(URI) as pe:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

That is the traceback that I receive in my terminal. 
If you need to see more of my code, please let me know. 
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You need to implement `__enter__` in your class and return self in it.

Comment: What are you expecting the `with Something(...) as something:` construct to do, exactly?

Comment: Also happens when you forget parenthesis eg: `with Session:`  instead of `with Session()` while using tensorflow

Comment: i got the same error when I was executing /tmp folder

Comment: Or if anyone is doing asynchronous programming, don't forget to put: `async with`

Comment: I doubt someone (except those who won't never make the same mistake) will be able to understand how the linked "duplicate" is actually answering the question on this page, or even whether there is a relationship between the two questions. And no other answer comes close to @BowlingHawk95 's one.

Comment: And also happens when you use `read()` inside `with open` so you should not do that

Answer (score 62):

More code would be appreciated (specifically the `ParamExample` implementation), but I'm assuming you're missing the `__enter__` (and probably `__exit__`) method on that class.

When you use a `with` block in python, the object in the with statement gets its `__enter__` method called, the block inside the `with` runs, and then the `__exit__` gets called (optionally with exception info if one was raised).  Thus, if you don't have an `__enter__` defined on your class, you'll see this error.

Side note: you need to either indent the second `with` block so it's actually inside the first, OR replace these two lines with

```
with ParamExample(URI) as pe, MotionCommander(pe, default_height=0.3) as mc:
```

which is the same as nesting these two context managers (the name of the objects used by `with` blocks).

Comment: As far as http://blog.lambdaconcept.com/doku.php?id=nmigen:nmigen_sim_testbench is concerned (same problem in tutorial) using "with" with Simulator is deprecated - just create and assign and make "process" as normal function