# Mongoengine find document without a field

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I need to find a document in the collection of `Chat` that contains no `deal` field. According to the documentation [`exists`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#query-operators) checks if the field exist, and [`first`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#limiting-and-skipping-results), is used to retrieve the first result, but the next line

```
Chat.objects.first(deal__exists=False)
```

raises `TypeError: first() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deal__exists'`

That's the `Chat` scheme

```
class Chat(Document):
    id = IntField(primary_key=True)
    name = StringField(default=CHANNEL_NAME)
    invite_link = StringField(default=None)
    deal = ReferenceField("Deal", default=None)
```

and current state of the only document in the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : XXXXXXXXX,
    "name" : "XXXXX",
    "invite_link" : "https://t.me/joinchat/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Value `none` for the `deal` gives the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
Chat.objects.get(deal__exists=False)
```

or

```
Chat.objects(deal__exists=False)[0]
```

to find the first result.

Comment: Results in `KeyError: 0`

Comment: do you have documents where deal doesnt exists?

Comment: Yep, there is currently only one document in the collection and current state of the document is in the question

Comment: mongoengine maintainer here, this is actually correct.
Double check your document from a mongo shell, I believe your document is different and has `deal: None` instead of not having the `deal` key

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while.

First of all, method `first` should be applied to the result of `Chat.objects(deal=None)`. Just like `Chat.objects(deal=None).first()`.

And it should not be used in `with` statement as it raises `AttributeError: __enter__`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427811/10420637) are more details on the error