# AttributeError: __enter__ During connection to mysql database

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting **AttributeError: __enter__** while executing the following code to get connection and cursor.

```
from contextlib import closing
def _connect():
    return closing(mysql.connect(
        host=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name'].get('HOST', 'localhost'),
        user=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name']['USER'],
        passwd=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name'].get('PASSWORD', ''),
        db=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name']['NAME'],
        cursorclass=cursors.DictCursor))

with _connect() as conn, conn as cursor:
```

I have got following error during execution.

```
with _connect() as conn, conn as cursor:
 AttributeError: __enter__
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427811/7994074

Comment: yes, i have written like this **with _connect() as conn, conn as cursor:** but it won't work.

Comment: @SaisivaA what do you expect `conn as cursor` to do exactly ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ofcourse i am executing quries with cursor......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with ContextDecorator as below.

```
from contextlib import ContextDecorator

class my_connect(ContextDecorator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_base_connection = ''

    def __enter__(self):
        self.data_base_connection = mysql.connect(
        host=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name'].get('HOST', 'localhost'),
        user=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name']['USER'],
        passwd=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name'].get('PASSWORD', ''),
        db=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name']['NAME'],
        cursorclass=cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor = self.data_base_connection.cursor()
        return cursor

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        self.data_base_connection.close()
        return False
```

In  query_tables() i just call my_connect() with **with** keyword

```
def query_tables():
    with my_connect() as cursor:
        #rest of the statements
```

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer then. It will make it easier for others to find.

Comment: `cursor = self.data_base_name.cursor()` will return an error `data_base_name.cursor() has no method cursor()`. I think you meant `cursor = self.data_base_connection.cursor()` please correct the corresponding line in your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it with your initial approach in this way. You don't need to create a class. Internally it will do exactly what you have done by creating a class but the code is more succinct IMHO.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def _connect():
    data_base_connection = mysql.connect(
    host=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name'].get('HOST', 'localhost'),
    user=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name']['USER'],
    passwd=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name'].get('PASSWORD', ''),
    db=settings.DATABASES['data_base_name']['NAME'],
    cursorclass=cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
       yield data_base_connection
    finally:
        data_base_connection.close()

def query_tables():
    with _connect() as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        # rest of the statements
```