# Saving tuple to database using pandas and sqlalchemy on mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a pandas `dataframe` containing different datatypes, like the one below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a', (4,5,6)],[1, 'b', (7,8,9)]])

print(df)
#    0  1          2
# 0  1  a  (4, 5, 6)
# 1  1  b  (7, 8, 9)

print(df.dtypes)
# 0     int64
# 1    object
# 2    object
# dtype: object
```

I want to save `df` to a MySql database using sqlalchemy and possibly pandas' `to_sql()` function.

The problem is that trying `df.to_sql(table_name, conn)` raises an exception because mysql connector doesn't nkow how to convert the tuple to a mysql type.

As a workaround, I turned the tuple in a string by using `apply()`, adding quotes around the tuples. This solution works and the tuple is written in the db as a string.

This is not ideal because when I read the table from the db I will have to convert strings containing a tuple back to tuples, which in my opinion is not the most elegant solution.

My question is: is there a better way to accomplish this?

Looking around I can't seem to find any simple solution to this problem

By the way, what I'm trying to do is to store sklearn model parametrizations in a db. The tuple problem arises when using `MLPRegressor` which wants a tuple for `hidden_layer_sizes` argument

Comment: *how to convert the tuple to a mysql type*...and what MySQL type do you intend? Usually RDBMS's are designed to store primitive types in bit form (boolean/string/numeric/date). It is not recommended to save complex application layer (i.e., python) types (i.e., tuple) in databases. Save underlying raw data, then rebuild in code as needed. Otherwise look into blob as listed [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) but I doubt this type works with pandas.

Comment: Yeah, I tried blob but had no luck. I guess the workaround is the actual solution then. Thanks for the help

Comment: Will tuples always be same length of three? If so save in different columns of pandas dataframe and then when imported from MySQL, bind them into tuples.

Comment: alas, they won't. I guess I'll stick to the string conversion

Comment: Alternatively, save tuples in different rows under one *values* column with repeated indicators (long format and preferable with data storage than the expensive wide format). And then just `groupby` back into tuples.

Comment: I might just try that, thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider storing tuple data in long format which can be saved appropriately in MySQL. Once read back into pandas, you can then `groupby(tuple)` to return to needed format for application work but again not to be saved in this format. Below is demonstration of different length tuples:

```
import pandas as pd

data_list = [[1, 'a', (4,5,6)],[1, 'b', (7,8,9,11,14)]]

dfs = [pd.DataFrame({'ID':i[0], 'LETTER':i[1], 'VALUES':i[2]}) for i in data_list]

df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(True)
print(df)
#    ID LETTER  VALUES
# 0   1      a       4
# 1   1      a       5
# 2   1      a       6
# 3   1      b       7
# 4   1      b       8
# 5   1      b       9
# 6   1      b      11
# 7   1      b      14


gdf = df.groupby(['ID', 'LETTER'])['VALUES'].apply(tuple).reset_index()
print(gdf)
#    ID LETTER             VALUES
# 0   1      a          (4, 5, 6)
# 1   1      b  (7, 8, 9, 11, 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work(worked for me)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql://user:passwd@127.0.0.1/db_name?charset=utf8')
df.to_sql('your_data',engine, flavor = 'mysql', if_exists= 'append')
```

Also check [writing to MySQL with pandas using SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631325/writing-to-mysql-database-with-pandas-using-sqlalchemy-to-sql)

Comment: I tried, but it gives an error, furthermore I just read that flavor is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: Execute works, but that's because it sees the tuple as a string I guess. I can try with mysql connector instead of sqlalchemy, but I don't thinkit'll work either