# Pandas and Fuzzy - comparing csv and mysql before overwriting

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

Based on the response presented in this topic [[Writing to MySQL database with pandas using SQLAlchemy, to_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631325/writing-to-mysql-database-with-pandas-using-sqlalchemy-to-sql]), how would it be possible, with pandas and fuzzywuzzy, to compare a csv file with the data in the database (in two columns) and if it already exists, overwrite information in two other columns, and if there is no addition of the entire row?

EDIT

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 

column_names = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5']

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header = None, names = column_names)
print(df)

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost')
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    df.to_sql('tableminysql', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I added the code in question