# I am getting a SQL unknown sql server error in last lines of my code

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python, streamlit

```
from logging import StreamHandler, exception
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from re import search
from pandas._config.config import options
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from pandas.core.tools import numeric
import streamlit as st       
import plotly.express as pt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import base64

#function
def filedownloader(database):
    csv = database.to_csv(index=False)
    b64 = base64.b64encode(csv.encode()).decode() 
    href = f'<a href="data:file/csv;base64,{b64}">Download csv file</a>'
    st.markdown(href,unsafe_allow_html=True)
    return href




#basic titles

st.title("Institution's Section")
st.sidebar.subheader("Settings")

# file uploader

fl=st.sidebar.file_uploader(label="Uplaod File in csv or xlsx format", type=['csv','xlsx'])
global df
if fl is not None:
    st.title("Performance Graph")
    try:
        df=pd.read_csv(fl)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        df=pd.read_excel(fl)

#write table in web page

global columns
try:
    st.write(df)
    columns = list(df.columns)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    st.write("Please upload a file")

#Chart select

st.sidebar.subheader("Analysis section")
ch=st.sidebar.selectbox(
    label="Select the chart type",
    options=['Scatterplots','Lineplots','Histogram','Boxplot'],
    key="chart"
)

#Plot Settings

if ch =='Scatterplots':
    st.sidebar.subheader("Scatterplot Settings")
    
    try:
        x_values=st.sidebar.selectbox('X axis',options=columns)
        y_values=st.sidebar.selectbox('Y axis',options=columns)
        plot=pt.scatter(data_frame=df,x=x_values,y=y_values)
        st.plotly_chart(plot)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
elif ch=='Lineplots':
    st.sidebar.subheader("Lineplot Settings")
    
    try:
        x_values=st.sidebar.selectbox('X axis',options=columns)
        y_values=st.sidebar.selectbox('Y axis',options=columns)
        plot=pt.line(data_frame=df,x=x_values,y=y_values)
        st.plotly_chart(plot)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
elif ch=='Histogram':
    st.sidebar.subheader("Histogram Settings")
    
    try:
        x_values=st.sidebar.selectbox('X axis',options=columns)
        y_values=st.sidebar.selectbox('Y axis',options=columns)
        plot=pt.histogram(data_frame=df,x=x_values,y=y_values)
        st.plotly_chart(plot)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
elif ch=='Boxplot':
    st.sidebar.subheader("Boxplot Settings")
    
    try:
        x_values=st.sidebar.selectbox('X axis',options=columns)
        y_values=st.sidebar.selectbox('Y axis',options=columns)
        plot=pt.box(data_frame=df,x=x_values,y=y_values)
        st.plotly_chart(plot)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

#rank select


st.sidebar.subheader("Quick Search Rank")
radio=st.sidebar.radio(
    "What you want to see?",("Top five","Bottom five")
)

#rank settings

numeric_column = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns.tolist()
if(radio=='Top five'):
    st.sidebar.subheader("Rank Settings")
    try:
        val=st.sidebar.selectbox('Select rank category',options=numeric_column)
        st.title("Quick Search Result")
        st.write(df.nlargest(5,val))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
elif(radio=='Bottom five'):
    st.sidebar.subheader("Rank Settings")
    try:
        val=st.sidebar.selectbox('Select rank category',options=numeric_column)
        st.title("Quick Search Result")
        st.write(df.nsmallest(5,val))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

#search

st.sidebar.subheader("Search")
val=st.sidebar.selectbox('Search desired column',options=columns)
st.sidebar.subheader("Search keyword")
user_input = st.sidebar.text_area("Type Keyword here", 0)
try: 
    dl = df[df[val] == type(df[val][1])(user_input)]
except Exception as e:
    pass

st.sidebar.subheader("Custom plot settings")
choose=st.sidebar.selectbox(
    label="Choose plot for selected data",
    options=['Scatterplot','Linearplot','Histogram','Boxplot',]
)
if(choose == 'Scatterplot'):
    try:
        st.sidebar.subheader("Scatterplot Settings")
        x_val=st.sidebar.selectbox('X axis',options=columns,key="scatter_x")
        y_val=st.sidebar.selectbox('Y axis',options=columns,key="scatter_y")
        plots=pt.scatter(data_frame=dl,x=x_val,y=y_val)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
elif (choose == 'Linearplot'):
    try:
        st.sidebar.subheader("Scatterplot Settings")
        x_val=st.sidebar.selectbox('X axis',options=columns,key="scatter_x")
        y_val=st.sidebar.selectbox('Y axis',options=columns,key="scatter_y")
        plots=pt.line(data_frame=dl,x=x_val,y=y_val)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
elif (choose == 'Histogram'):
    try:
        st.sidebar.subheader("Scatterplot Settings")
        x_val=st.sidebar.selectbox('X axis',options=columns,key="scatter_x")
        y_val=st.sidebar.selectbox('Y axis',options=columns,key="scatter_y")
        plots=pt.histogram(data_frame=dl,x=x_val,y=y_val)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
elif (choose == 'Boxplot'):
    try:
        st.sidebar.subheader("Scatterplot Settings")
        x_val=st.sidebar.selectbox('X axis',options=columns,key="scatter_x")
        y_val=st.sidebar.selectbox('Y axis',options=columns,key="scatter_y")
        plots=pt.box(data_frame=dl,x=x_val,y=y_val)
    except Exception as e:
        pass

#chart and search button

bt=st.sidebar.button("Search and Apply")
if(bt):
    st.title("Search Results")
    st.write(dl)
    st.title("Searh Analysis")
    st.plotly_chart(plots)

#Modify database
st.sidebar.subheader("Select Column to drop null values")
val1=st.sidebar.multiselect(
    label="Selet Columns",
    options=columns
)
bt_null_r=st.sidebar.button("Drop Null values")
if(bt_null_r):
    mdf=df.dropna(subset=val1, how='all')
    filedownloader(mdf)

# drop selected column
st.sidebar.subheader("Select Column to drop null values")
val2=st.sidebar.multiselect(
    label="Selet Columns",
    options=columns,key="column_multi"
)
bt_c=st.sidebar.button("Drop Columns")
if(bt_c):
    mdf=df.drop(val2,axis=1)
    filedownloader(mdf)
**#creating sql engine
engine=create_engine('mysql://root:Soumik18@@localhost:3306/college')
df.to_sql('Students',con=engine)**
```

Where might I be going wrong? I am using MySQL with Heidi SQL. In the last 2 lines I am using the SQL code and I have my local host assigned to 127.0.0.1 and have port 3306 and my password is Soumik18@. What can I do?

I am getting this error:

> OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '@localhost' (11003)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

Comment: Have you tried `quote_plus('YOUR_PASSWORD')` in the connection string? `'mysql://%s:%s@localhost:3306/college' % (quote_plus(USERNAME), quote_plus(PASS))`? https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing to MySQL database with pandas using SQLAlchemy, to\_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631325/writing-to-mysql-database-with-pandas-using-sqlalchemy-to-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things to check:

1. Can you connect to MySQL outside of the script with the credentials
   you provided (`mysql -u root -p`)?  If yes, then there may be a configuration problem in your script to connect. If not, confirm MySQL is running, then re-check your password. If a potential password issue, may be worth restarting MySQL by adding `skip_grant_tables` under your configuration file and restarting so you can log in w/o a password and reset the root password.
2. Did you modify the MySQL configuration in any way, specifically the `bind-address`? By default, MySQL sets this to 127.0.0.1, so you may want to try connecting with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.
3. If this is a non-Windows machine, is /etc/hosts configured properly for localhost (ex: `127.0.0.1       localhost`)?

I use a different method to connect to MySQL via Python, so I am not as familiar with sqlalchemy.